# How to setup Selenium Server on RedHat linux?

Tags: linux, selenium, redhat, selenium-grid

I am trying to download the standlone jar file on my machine, but it is headless so I do not know what approach to take.

I have looked at similar questions which state

```
wget http://selenium.googlecode.com/files/selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar
```

to be a solution, but when I try this, it returns Network is unreachable.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabled corporate proxy and then download worked.

Used another link too: 
http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.4/selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar